# Find IP of website

Tags: dns, ip

Usually I'm able to find website IP with ping / nslookup / tracert.
After Finding the IP I can write it in the address bar of the browser to reach the website.
But in some cases, for exmample, www.ynet.co.il, I get an IP address which I cannot reach the website if I write it on the address bar.
Can anybody help and explain what is the diffrent?
Thanks, 
Tomer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, basically the site is run with many other sites on one ip address -which is standard for like 20 years or so.

The browser also sends the domain name as part of the http request. If you type the ip address, it can not do it. Ergo the server does not know which site to serve.